# gradle error when use TextInputLayout

Tags: android, gradle, android-manifest, android-textinputlayout

I'm trying to use `TextInputLayout` but i am getting **Manifest merger failed**.this Causing to gradle error. following text to show gradle message:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.1) from [com.android.support:design:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31
is also present at [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:34 to override.
```

Projects `minSdkVersion is 19`, `targetSdkVersion is 26` and `compileSdkVersion is 26` with `buildToolsVersion 25.0.2` and gradle dependencies in project is :

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
```

Comment: Why aren't you using version 26 for the design library?

Comment: This is the default project, I did not choose anything

Comment: I don't think the default project sets the alpha version for the v7 library... But I also haven't create a new project in some time

Comment: yes,you are right. i change `appcompat-v7:26.+` to `appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1`

Comment: Okay, again, why did you not also change the `support:design` to also be `26.+`?

Comment: humm , i don't have idea. that's IDE suggestion !
problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that both versions are the same:

`compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'`

or

`compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'`

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you work with a stable version of SDK, since when you try a newer version and it is in alpha or beta version have some bugs, possibly that is your case: [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0- Alpha1]

Try using the SKD 25 version.

compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'